# How to open a url link inside a div and stay on current url at the same time?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, software-design

I am trying to use a icon I have, where when click expands like I am opening a browser and inside that expanded div "browser" pulls up a URL I attach. How do I achieve pulling up a new url thats interactive inside my original index.html without leaving my index.html or opening it on a new tab?

I know how make a div clickable to expand the screen, but not how to make that div turn into the url I want it to be without opening a new tab or leaving my index.html.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is AJAX

Comment: What would I be attempting with AJAX? Never used it.

Comment: You want to fetch a remote URL and load the content within your current page? Well, use AJAX to request the remote URL and the callback function to process the remote url content.

Comment: What exactly is the content of the "new URL"? Is it another website? Or is it an API endpoint which returns JSON? Or is it a URL which returns a static file?

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Arshaan's answer, this may not work if the target site refuses to be iframed (see [clickjacking](/questions/tagged/clickjacking)).

If you use a `<div>` instead of an `<iframe>`, you may find that you cannot load the other site via AJAX if it is not [cors](/questions/tagged/cors)-enabled. Even if you can load the HTML and insert it into the `<div>`, if the embedded HTML then loads Javascript, that may interact with the rest of your HTML page in unforseen ways.

To summarize: This is unlikely to work in general.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Iframes (instead of simple div):

```
<iframe src="The url you want to show" title="its description"></iframe>
```

you can also change its look with css:

```
iframe {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: none;
}
```